# Error using LsqFit and CurveFit Julia

Tags: julia, curve-fitting

I installed the LsqFit packages and `CurveFit` in `Julia`, and when I run `LsqFit` the following error occurs:

> LoadError: MethodError: `curve_fit` has no method matching curve_fit (::Function, ::linspace Float64 {}, {Float64,1} :: Array, Array :: {} Float64,1)
>       Closest candidates are: 
>       curve_fit(!Matched::Type{CurveFit.RationalPoly{T<:Number}}, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any) 
>       curve_fit(!Matched::Type{CurveFit.RationalPoly{T<:Number}}, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any) 
>       curve_fit(!Matched::Type{CurveFit.RationalPoly{T<:Number}}, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any)
>       ...
>       while loading In [12], in expression starting on line 14

How to solve?

Comment: how do you call `curve_fit`? add more information.

Comment: `LsqFit` and `CurveFit` packages have different implementation of `curve_fit`. From the error that you have included, I understand that you `using CurveFit` but call `curve_fit` with the syntax from the other package. `LsqFit` in not depend on `CurveFit` so the only line you must add in `using  LsqFit`.

Comment: Hi  
I solved the problem changing the name "curve_fit"  to "Curve_fit" in Curvefit package. But, is possible to use "Curvefit.curve_fit" and "LsqFit.curve_fit" when the names are equal

Comment: It's good practice, IMO, to always use `import` instead of `using` so that you don't get namespace conflicts like this